# When does Task.Run(Action, CancellationToken) throw TaskCanceledException?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160373(v=vs.110).aspx) `Task.Run(Action, CancellationToken)` throws `TaskCanceledException` when the task has been canceled.

When exactly does `Task.Run(Action, CancellationToken)` throw `TaskCanceledException`? It is not clear what conditions must be met for this exception to be thrown.

Comment: Have you checked the example on the page you linked to in your question?

Comment: @zerkms, I have checked the example. It shows that TaskCanceledException is thrown by Task.Wait() method and not by Task.Run(). I am trying to understand under which conditions Task.Run() throws TaskCancelledException.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion (and the documentation might be misleading).

Inoking the `Task.Run` method would **never** throw `TaskCanceledException` (at least with the current implementation). Unlike `ArgumentNullException` and `ObjectDisposedException` that are thrown synchronously when the "The action parameter was null" and "The CancellationTokenSource associated with cancellationToken was disposed." respectively.

`Task.Run` however returns a `Task` that may be canceled using the `CancellationToken` parameter (more on cancellation in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx)) and waiting on it with `await task`, `task.Wait()`, `task.Result`, etc. would throw a `TaskCanceledException` (possibly wrapped in an `AggregateException`)

```
Task<int> task = null;
try
{
    task = Task.Run(() => 5, new CancellationToken(true));
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unreachable code");
}

try
{
    int result = await task;
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Awaiting a canceled task");
}
```

It might be clearer if the documentation had 2 sections of possible exceptions:

1. "regular" synchronous exceptions (e.g. `ArgumentNullException` and `ObjectDisposedException`)
2. "async" asynchronous exceptions that could only be thrown by waiting on the returned task (e.g. `TaskCanceledException`)

Comment: @l3arnon, this sounds very reasonable. How did you find out that invoking the Task.Run method would never throw TaskCanceledException?

Comment: @Alex well, experience. But if you're willing to go down the rabbit hole you can look at the [source code for `Task.Run`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5faac53c590b086f) and see only the other exceptions being thrown synchronously.

Comment: The documentation blows.

Comment: **"Task.Run however returns a Task that may be canceled using the CancellationToken parameter (more on cancellation in here) and waiting on it with await task, task.Wait(), task.Result, etc. would throw a TaskCanceledException"** -- well this is very misleading. Just "cancel" by the source without explicitly throwing in user code, it will never cause `await task` to throw `TaskCanceledException`, except that when cancel happens before task start; as for `Wait`, `Wait()` won't throw if cancelled, but `Wait(token)` does. I haven't tried the `Result`, so no comment on that one.

Comment: @Tomingsun `Wait` (and `Result`) on a cancelled task throw a `TaskCanceledException` wrapped in the usual aggregate exception.  As to co-operative cancellation.. you're right. I didn't think that was the OP's issue though. You're more than invited to edit the answer and expand on it.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [*Cancellation in Managed Thread*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Only the requesting object can issue the cancellation request, and **each listener is responsible for noticing the request and responding to it in a timely manner.**

And then goes on:

> Cancellation is **cooperative and is not forced on the listener.** The listener determines how to gracefully terminate in response to a cancellation request.

You need to make sure you're listening on `CancellationToken.IsCancelledRequested` or the exception throwing `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancelltionRequested`. Its *your* responsibility to cancel and `await` the operation to observethe cancellation exception.