# What is the difference between Task.Run and Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

I know this question has been asked before, but I didn't get the right answer after googling SO.

I have these lines of code:

```
Task.Run(() => DoSomething())
    .ContinueWith(t=>Log.Error(t,"Error"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething())
    .ContinueWith(t=>Log.Error(t,"Error"),TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

After a successful run of `DoSomething`, `Task.Run` throws `TaskCanceledException` while `Task.Factory.StartNew` works fine. Why?

further reading:
[Stephen Clearly on why not use Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)
[MSDN Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)

**UPDATE 2:** 
Sample Code:

```
private async void button27_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var r = new Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => {
            Divide(r.Next(100), r.Next(-1, 10));
            Log.Information("Divide Done!");
        },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
        TaskScheduler.Default)
    .ContinueWith(
        t => {
            Log.Error(t.Exception,"There is an exception on Divide");
        },
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}

private static void Divide(int a, int b)
{
    var c = a/b;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regarding usage of Task.Start() , Task.Run() and Task.Factory.StartNew()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693362/regarding-usage-of-task-start-task-run-and-task-factory-startnew)

Comment: No, it's not. It does not answer my question which is why throwing exception occurs. It describes what I already know. Thanks.

Comment: I have rolled back your question, because you completely changed the it, invalidating existing answers. If you have a new question, please post a new question.

Comment: @Sepinood - Ok, I retracted the close-vote. Even though I believe the title _What is the difference between Task.Run and Task.Factory.StartNew?_ is answered in the suggested duplicate. And all the current answers more or less states the same thing as the suggested duplicate and quotes the same source.

Comment: @smoksnes Thanks for your time. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Task.Run is actually implemented in terms of the same logic used for
>   Task.Factory.StartNew, just passing in some default parameters.  When
>   you pass an Action to Task.Run:

```
Task.Run(someAction);
```

> that’s exactly equivalent to:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction, 
    CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Read more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

If you pass `CancellationToken.None`, `TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach` and `TaskScheduler.Default` arguments for `Task.Factory.StartNew` parameters you should see the same result.

Comment: @Sepinood: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577519/why-is-taskcanceledexception-thrown-and-does-not-always-breaks-into-the-debugger or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196451/when-does-task-runaction-cancellationtoken-throw-taskcanceledexception

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. I updated the question totally. I think it is related to design of TPL.

Comment: You won't see the exact same behavior, there is one important diffrence. `Task.Run(` has overloads that take in a `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>` as the paremeter. This allows you to pass in async functions in to `Task.Run(` if you try to do a async function with `StartNew(` you must call `.Unwrap()` on the returned task to get the same behavior.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the brilliant set of details for good clarity